# Remove duplicate widget

Tags: list, dart, flutter

[image]My function types() should return a unique list of ExpansionTiles. 
In dart combining .toSet().toList() is really efficient in removing duplicates in List and I am trying to do the same here but I'm still rendering duplicates.

In the picture I don't want NISSAN to appear twice, just once as one category.

```
types() {
 return snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) { 
   if(doc['car']['registryNumber'] != null && doc['car']['category'] == 
   'car') {
     return ExpansionTile(
       title: new Row(
       children: <Widget>[
         new Text(
          doc['car']['type'].split(' ')[0],
          style: new TextStyle(
           fontSize: 15.0
          ),
         )
       ],
       ),
       children: <Widget>[

       ],
     );
     } else {  
      return new Text('');
   }
  }).toSet().toList();
}
```

Comment: you do toSet() on the list of ExpansionTiles but you should do it on list of car names

Comment: Got it! before returning the Widget I applied toSet() to the list of car names. All good now!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add a unique `key:` to `ExpansionTile` to avoid any duplicate issues!